# Using Findroot with Precompiled Function

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning, numerics, compile

I am writing a Monte Carlo algorithm to solve some algebraic equations. To do this I need to evaluate FindRoot many times on the same function. 
Following from F'x's answer to
[Expression evaluation inside of FindRoot inside a Compiled Function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3961/expression-evaluation-inside-of-findroot-inside-a-compiled-function), 
I understand that FindRoot will compile the target function each time it is evaluated, and so the fastest way for me to work with FindRoot is to combine the function myself beforehand. This should save FindRoot compiling each time I run it.

I can't however work out the syntax to do this. My toy example code is:

```
f[x_] := x^x + (4 - x)^(4 - x) - 10
g = Compile[{x}, x^x + (4 - x)^(4 - x) - 10];
FindRoot[f[x], {x, 3.99}, Compiled -> False] // Timing
FindRoot[f[x], {x, 3.99}] // Timing
FindRoot[g[x], {x, 3.99}, Compiled -> False] // Timing
FindRoot[g[x], {x, 3.99}] // Timing
```

None of the ones with `g` work; I get `CompiledFunction::cfsa`, and the `g` ones are slower so I assume this is inputting the uncompiled function.

I have tried also

`FindRoot[g, {x, 3.99}]
FindRoot[g, {x, 3.99},Compiled-> False]`

Which don't evaluate to anything.

What is the correct syntax for this?
Or if I've misunderstood the quoted article, could someone explain what I should be doing?

Comment: Try `FindRoot[g, {3.99}]`. If a function is supplied, no symbol is needed. If you would like to use Newton's method, you have to supply a (compiled) function `Dg` also for the `Jacobian`, e.g. with `FindRoot[g, {3.99}, Jacobian -> Dg]`. For scalar function one may have to fiddle a bit with braces in `Dg` such that `Dg[x]` becomes a 1 x 1 matrix; Mathematica will complain otherwise.

Comment: Why do you need to use `FindRoot` many times on the *same* function? Won't it always return the same answer? I assume the function must have some changes upon each invocation of `FindRoot`. Could you clarify what these changes are?

Comment: none of them work? Even the ones where you use `f`?

Comment: Thank you Henrik Schumacher you have solved my problem. 
Carl Woll; I am using a Monte Carlo algorithm, so this basically means that I guess a lot of times until I find all of the solutions of a given function. So yes, I do use exactly the same function lots of times

Comment: somebody should make that an answer. @HenrikSchumacher

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Interesting. How did you figure out this hidden syntax?

Comment: @xzczd I wondered what Chuck Norris would do if he had to implement `FindRoot` and just gave it a try.

Comment: I think your solution is absolutely intuitive and makes complete sense now that I see it, but I wasn't going to get there just by thinking about Chuck Norris on my own though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I cast my comment into an answer...

To my own surprise, `FindRoot[g, {3.99}]` works well. If a function is supplied, no symbol is needed. So the current implementation of `FindRoot` can decide very early that symbolic computation (and maybe further compilation) is futile and it branches to a completely numerical algorithm.

If you would like to use Newton's method, you have to supply a (compiled) function `Dg` also for the Jacobian, e.g. with `FindRoot[g, {3.99}, Jacobian -> Dg]`. For a scalar function one may have to fiddle a bit with braces in `Dg` such that `Dg[x]` becomes a 1 x 1 matrix; Mathematica will complain otherwise.

See also [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/163255/findroot-with-a-precompiled-function-with-parameters/163258#163258) for details.

Answer (score 4):

The key to the `CompiledFunction::cfsa` error is the option `RuntimeOptions -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}`.  Maybe this is what you were expecting:

```
f[x_] := x^x + (4 - x)^(4 - x) - 10
g = Compile[{x}, x^x + (4 - x)^(4 - x) - 10, 
   RuntimeOptions -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}];
FindRoot[f[x], {x, 3.99}, Compiled -> False] // RepeatedTiming
FindRoot[f[x], {x, 3.99}] // RepeatedTiming
FindRoot[g[x], {x, 3.99}, Compiled -> False] // RepeatedTiming
FindRoot[g[x], {x, 3.99}] // RepeatedTiming
(*
  {0.00047, {x -> 2.37473}}
  {0.00048, {x -> 2.37473}}

  {0.00036, {x -> 2.37473}}
  {0.00036, {x -> 2.37473}}
*)
```

***Without*** the option setting, the compiled function evaluates symbolically:

```
g[x]
```

> CompiledFunction::cfsa: Argument x at position 1 should be a machine-size real number.

```
(*  -10 + (4 - x)^(4 - x) + x^x  *)
```

`FindRoot` evaluates the argument symbolically to be able compute the derivative.  And it probably uses the symbolic results and then compiles them (or in the case of `g[x]`, recompiles them).  So to get the benefit of precompiling `g`, you need to do something to prevent `FindRoot` from evaluating `g` symbolically.  One way is the option `RuntimeOptions -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}`; the other is to use [`_?NumericQ`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037) as in `h`.

Comment: Michael, I think a timing comparison between memoized and unmemoized secant method with `RepeatedTiming` would be only fair if you erase the memoized values of `h` in between.

Comment: `FindRoot[h[x], {x, 3.99}] // RepeatedTiming` evaluates `FindRoot[h[x], {x, 3.99}]` several times and since `h` is memoized, `g` will be called only in the first of these runs, since `h` will already know what its values are afterwards. But that's not the typical situation "in free hunting ground". So, the `Clear[h]` should also be embraced by `RepeatedTiming`. An alternative could be to use random numbers as initial guess for `FindRoot`...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Yep, even though the derivative takes twice as long to evaluate than the function, the overhead of `FindRoot` dominates the timingin this example.  Indeed, the overhead of memoizing is measurable.

Comment: Michael, just to clarify: I did not doubt that the secant method can perform better than Newton's method. My comment is just about the memoization overhead.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher My take-away is that in univariate cases, it's usually not worth taking an extra step to get `FindRoot` to use Newton's method.