# Jacobian for parallelised FindRoot with multiple variables

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning, numerics, parallelization

Michael E2 explains how to use parallel processing to speed up multiple `FindRoot` calculation with the same function in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/163295/40271.

An example of some code which does this is

```
f[x_] := x^x + (4 - x)^(4 - x) - 20;
df0[x_?VectorQ] = D[f[x], x];
df[x_?VectorQ] := DiagonalMatrix@SparseArray@df0[x];
params = RandomReal[{2, 3}, 10];
FindRoot[f[x], {x, params}, Jacobian :> df[x]]
```

I would now like to extend this to work in more than one variable. A syntax to do this is quite simple;

```
f[x_, y_] := {x^x + y^y - 20, x + y - 4}
inits = RandomReal[{2, 3}, {2, 10}];
FindRoot[f[x,y], {{x, inits[[1]]}, {y, inits[[2]]}}]
```

However I can't find the right syntax to add in an explicit Jacobian. My example code is

```
f[x_, y_] := {x^x + y^y - 20, x + y - 4}
df0[x_, y_] = Outer[D, f[x, y], {x,y}];
df[x_, y_] := df0[x, y]
inits = RandomReal[{2, 3}, {2, 10}];
Block[{x, y}, 
  FindRoot[f[x, y], {{x, inits[[1]]}, {y, inits[[2]]}}, 
   Jacobian :> df[x, y]]]
```

And I get an error that `The Jacobian is not a matrix of numbers at {x,y} = inits`. So I try instead

```
f[x_, y_] := {x^x + y^y - 20, x + y - 4}
df0[x_, y_] = Outer[D, f[x, y], {x,y}];
SetAttributes[df, Listable];
df[x_, y_] := df0[x, y]
inits = RandomReal[{2, 3}, {2, 10}];
Block[{x, y}, 
  FindRoot[f[x, y], {{x, inits[[1]]}, {y, inits[[2]]}}, 
   Jacobian :> df[x, y]]]
```

Which produces the same error, however in this case if I evaluate `df@@inits`, I do indeed get a list of matrices of numbers. So I am confused about this.

I have tried also with explicit `?VectorQ`, like so;

```
f[x_?VectorQ, y_?VectorQ] := {x^x + y^y - 20, x + y - 4}
df0[x_?VectorQ, y_?VectorQ] = 
  Outer[D, {x^x + y^y - 20, x + y - 4}, {x, y}];
df[x_?VectorQ, y_?VectorQ] := df0[x, y];
inits = RandomReal[{2, 3}, {2, 10}];
FindRoot[f[x, y], {{x, inits[[1]]}, {y, inits[[2]]}}, 
 Jacobian :> df[x, y]]
```

And this doesn't work either.

Who knows how to do this?

Comment: You can mark a "block of code" by indenting each line with 4 spaces. This can easily be done by selecting the code portion and pressing Ctrl+K.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll do that next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The major problem is to have a fast way to obtain a block diagonal matrix. Moreover, there is a problem with the vectorization of `df`. In the following I skip the vectorization part (for complicated functions in several variables, vectorization is not always more performant).

```
xx = Table[Compile`GetElement[x, i], {i, 1, 2}];
f = x \[Function] Evaluate[N[{xx[[1]]^xx[[1]] + xx[[2]]^xx[[2]] - 20, xx[[1]] + xx[[2]] - 4}]];
Df = x \[Function] Evaluate[N[D[f[xx], {xx, 1}]]];
```

Regarding the block diagonal matrix, I compute its column indices and row pointers by hand and store them for later use in `DF`.

```
m = Length[xx];
n = 10000;    
ci = Flatten[
   Transpose[{Partition[Partition[Range[m n], 1], m]}[[ConstantArray[ 1, m]]]], 
  2];
rp = Range[0, m m n, m];
```

`F` and `DF` are sort of wrapper functions that constitute the high dimensional system. I use `BlockMap` in order to apply `f` and `Df` to flat list of length `2 n`. **This is actually where the block diagonal matrix is produced.**

```
F = X \[Function] Flatten@(BlockMap[f, X, m]);
DF = X \[Function] SparseArray @@ {Automatic, {m n, m n}, 
     0., {1, {rp, ci}, Flatten[BlockMap[Df, X, m]]}};
```

For speeding up even further (and as substitute for vectorization), I also compile `f` and `Df` and create wrapper functions for them.

```
With[{code = f[xx]},
  cf = Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}},
    code,
    CompilationTarget -> "C",
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
    Parallelization -> True,
    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
    ]
  ];
With[{code = Df[xx]},
  cDf = Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}},
    code,
    CompilationTarget -> "C",
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
    Parallelization -> True,
    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
    ]
  ];
cF = X \[Function] cf[Partition[Abs[X], m]];
cDF = X \[Function] SparseArray @@ {Automatic, {m n, m n}, 0., {1, {rp, ci}, Flatten[cDf[Partition[Abs[X], m]]]}};
```

Now, we have at least 4 ways to solve the systems; let's try them out and compare! (I use `Quiet` to suppress some errors that get produced in the compiled function, probalby during the line search...)

```
X = X0 = RandomReal[{2, 3}, {n m}];

Y = Map[x \[Function] FindRoot[f, {{x}}, Jacobian -> Df], 
    Partition[X0, m]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
cY = Quiet[Map[x \[Function] FindRoot[cf, {{x}}, Jacobian -> cDf], 
     Partition[X0, m]]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
X = FindRoot[F, {X0}, Jacobian -> DF][[1]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
cX = Quiet[FindRoot[cF, {X0}, Jacobian -> cDF][[1]]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 3.29515
>
> 2.45185
>
> 1.19915
>
> 0.353124

Residuals:

```
Max[Abs[F[Flatten[Y]]]]
Max[Abs[F[Flatten[cY]]]]
Max[Abs[F[X]]]
Max[Abs[F[cX]]]
```

> 8.52651*10^-14
>
> 8.52651*10^-14
>
> 3.55271*10^-15
>
> 3.55271*10^-15

And the differences are:

```
Max[Abs[Flatten[X] - Flatten[Y]]]
Max[Abs[Flatten[X] - Flatten[cY]]]
Max[Abs[Flatten[X] - Flatten[cX]]]
```

> 2.88658*10^-15
>
> 2.88658*10^-15
>
> 6.66134*10^-16

Comment: OK so I just threw this into Mathematica and I haven't really understood what's going on in too much detail yet. I get `CompiledFunction::cfne: Numerical error encountered; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation.` on the lines when you actually do the calculation. Is that what you were suppressing with `Quiet`? Is this a problem or not?

Comment: Also what is the purpose of the `Compile GetElement`? I see you and the other `Compile` wizards use this a lot and I don't really get what's wrong with `Part` within `Compile`?

Comment: OK further questions: 1) Why do we have `Abs` in `cF = X \[Function] cf[Partition[Abs[X], 2]];`? Isn't this restricting the domain of the function to be only positive real numbers or something? I don't think I want to do that.
2) I guess that the `{Automatic, {m n, m n}, 
   0., {1, {rp, ci}, Flatten[BlockMap[Df, X, m]]}}` is a set of options for `Jacobian` in `FindRoot`? Can you run me through what each one is? I can't see them in the documentation

Comment: The F and the DF, I presumably won't need these if I implement your fourth (fastest) method in my algorithm, and they're just to show that it's quicker with `Compile`?
You also talk about a block diagonal matrix, but I can't actually see any block diagonal matrices anywhere?
Why do we have to turn off `Part::partd`?

Comment: Turning off `Part::partd`: I edited the post. Supressing error messages should better avoided and if necessay, should only be done locally.

Comment: About `Quiet`: You equations are somewhat nasty: The exponential functions lead easily to something that is not treatable by machine precision real numbers (for example, if `x` is negative than `x^x` has to be computed in the complex numbers - and it is also no continuous any more. I think this happens when `FindRoot` makes a step into the negative numbers. Due to backtracking line search, this does not cause severe problems since the step size is sufficiently reduced; but during the linesearch, `cF` might get evaluated for invalid inputs; this is why the warnings occur.

Comment: Yeah, you don't need `F` and `DF`. In general use `cF` and `cDF`.

Comment: Towards the block diagonal matrix: Just set `n=10` and evaluted `cDF[X0] // MatrixPlot` or `cDF[X0] // Normal`; then you well see it. I build the matrix with quite a dirty trick, but it is much faster than building it with the standard syntax for `SparseArray`.

Comment: Towards ``Compile`GetElement``: It is a read-only operation and in that respect, it does basically the same as Part. But it suppresses bound checks in the generated C-code: Instead of asking: "Please, please with sugar on top: Is array `x` long enough that `i` really indexes into it? If yes, please give be `x[[i]]`. If no, please throw an error." it just states "Give me `x[[i]]`. Believe me, it will work". Of course, that can lead to severe trouble if `i` does not really index into `x`. So it is in the responsibility of the user to assure that.

Comment: Thanks for all of your answers. OK so I now understand the block diagonal matrix. You've made all of the repeated calculations into one big system and you just run `FindRoot` once. Why was it faster to do it this way? How does `FindRoot` know to parallelise this kind of computation? Also, can you explain how `SparseArray` works with the `{1, {rp, ci}, Flatten[BlockMap[Df, X, m]]}` syntax? The documentation isn't too enlightening for me on this. Finally, am I likely to run into problems if I change `_Real` to `_Complex`?

Comment: `FindRoot` parallelizes nothing; it mere applies Newton's algorithm (with some tricks, e.g. line search or trust region). Newton's method  is basically computing `x =x - LinearSolve[cDF[x],cF[x]]` recursively until a suitable stopping criterion is met. The parallelization is happening in `cf` and `cDf`. To some extend, also `LinearSolve` profits from the fact, that we reduce the number of calls to it.

Comment: For the `SparseArray` syntax, see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18081/how-to-interpret-the-fullform-of-a-sparsearray).

Comment: Thank you for an excellent solution to my problem, and for all of your answers to my questions. Just to note, there are some `2` in your code that should be `m`, it might be useful for someone else to change these. I see one in `ci`, and also in the definitons of `cF`, `cDF`, `Y` and `cY`.

Comment: @Joe You're welcome! And thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Ah, I've just started to implement this in my real-use case and I'm not sure if it'll work for what I'm doing. I'm solving equations by Monte-Carlo, so what happens is I `FindRoot` at the `n` random initial points, to 1 digit of precision but with very many iterations. Then if a solution converges to 1 d.p. I keep it, and any that fail a `Check` for `FindRoot` error messages are thrown away. I then home in on the 1.d.p. solutions to higher accuracy, and repeat the process comparing the ones that hit against previously generated solutions.

Comment: So of the `n` trials, I expect that some will converge maybe quite quickly, and I don't want the algorithm to continue running for these ones. But many will run all the way to the end, but never converge, and I want these ones to return some error message. Is this possible somehow with your code? This part of the algorithm also works with a fixed `n`, but then the second part which homes in on solutions varies `n` depending on how many we found, so it looks to me like this won't work with what you've written either, as I think your code requires `n` to be fixed?